# RelativeLayout layout_alignBottom of TextView doesn't work properly

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

Trying to do some alignment by a flexible TextView, in a RelativeLayout container that may vary in height. 
Seems like no brainer, and yet, it doesn't align anywhere near where it should.

The following simple code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<-- Stands for any view that would force minimum height, e.g. an avatar image -->
<View
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:background="#300f"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ceterum censeo carthaginem esse delendam"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/t1"
    android:background="#6f00"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

One may obviously expect that the red rectangle would align vertically with the text. But it doesn't.

What has gone wrong?...

Comment: Try to use android:layout_below="@+id/t1".

Comment: add android:layout_centerVertical="true" to your red color layout

Comment: @Ahamed I wish! But I can't. It should be aligned, the heights should align, e.g when the text is long and the line grows higher...

Comment: You have been set the Parent layout height to wrap_content and set the height of the blue color view to 73dp. so the parent layout takes the height of the blue color view. then the textview getting center position because of you have been set the property android:centerVertical="true". so the textview got the center position. then you have set the value to wrap_content of red color view. so, what you want to do is, you must set the property value android:centerVertical="true" to red color view . otherwise, you can set the parent layout height to match_parent . then you will see the effect

Comment: check my updated answer. let me know if it is works otherwise, we will go with another solution

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with you relative layout height is set to wrap_content.

from [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) documentation:

> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of
>   the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you
>   cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a
>   child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.

So either you set that height to match_parent or, easier, like [Ahamed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264221/relativelayout-layout-alignbottom-of-textview-doesnt-work-properly#comment69729297_41264221) wrote 
add android:layout_centerVertical="true" to your red color layout

Comment: Dude, there is no circular dependency. The text view is already aligned to the centre, and the red view is aligned to the textView bottom.

Comment: Please read the code. There is no circular dependency. The text view is already aligned to the centre, and the red view is aligned to the textView bottom. Simple as that.
So, the dependency is: 
h(RelativeLayout)=h(Blue View) because it's wrap_content
h(TextView) is wrapped by its content. 
Position(TextView) is centredVertical
h(RedView) is absolute.
Position(RedView) is the bottom of the textview.

That's it. No circular dependency.
The dependency tree is:
RedView->TextView->RelativeLayout->BlueView

Height(RelativeLayout) = max(children) 
Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

user  android:layout_below="@id/id"

```
<View
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/t1"
  android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
    android:background="#6f00"/>
```

I hope It's work

Comment: Absolutely not... It constraints from below, but in the wrong place. Doing that would make it just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
try using the attribute "android:layout_below". For example:
...
<View android:id="@+id/v1"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:background="#300f"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ceterum censeo carthaginem esse delendam"/>

...
```

Comment: Please... It's a circular dependency. And it would not work anyway because the aim is to force it to behave the other way round.

Comment: Then wrap the textview and the second view into a linearLayout view and set the linearlayout view below the first view...duh!

Comment: LinearLayout costs in performance, and you can't align other stuff under its children.
This is a simplified case. To cut the long story short, not good enough when you want to align in several axes :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View android:id="@+id/some_view_id"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:background="#300f"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_view_id"
        android:text="varying text view here that can \n go for multiple lines and not disturb the one below"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/t1"
        android:background="#6f00"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Obviously not, you would not wanna put it below, you want to put it inline

Comment: You mean, all 3 in same line ?

Comment: I just mean that I want to align the bottom of the red one with the bottom of the text. That's what alignBottom is all about :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may solve your problem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<View
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:background="#300f" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ceterum censeo carthaginem esse delendam" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:background="#6f00" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Meymann...I cannot cleary identify what's your exact problem is!...can you explain cleary and how your layout should be.Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply, the text view centred, and the red view aligned to its bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_toEndOf`  like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ceterum censeo carthaginem esse delendam"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/t1"
    android:background="#6f00"/>
```

Comment: To End Of is horizontal constraint!

Comment: When you use it red rectangle will be aligned with TextView and placed behind it, if you want it in front use `android:layout_toStartOf`

Comment: The horizontal location doesn't matter right now. I talked about vertical alignment, not horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. hope this helps.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <View
       android:layout_width="10dp"
       android:layout_height="73dp"
       android:background="#300f"/>
    <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true">

      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/t1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="ceterum censeo carthaginem esse delendam"/>

      <View
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/t1"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/t1"
         android:background="#6f00"/>
   </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish, again. This was my original attempt :( The whole truth is that instead of the 2nd internal view I had to put in an ImageView (Simplified the example as much as possible for the question). Not much success.
I get the feeling that RelativeLayout doesn't calculate dependencies properly, unless they are straight forward. They ought to, as they do measure cycle and then positioning. That should solve wrap_content vs centerVertical pseudo mutual dependency.
Might need to dig into Android's code for that.

Comment: is this solution OK for you?

Comment: Nope. See my comment. That was the original code (with ImageView instead). I simplified it for the question.